# Change WooCommerce product quantity settings for specific product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-quantity

I have this code that adds input quantity value on the archive (shop) page.

```
 // For implementation instructions see: https://aceplugins.com/how-to-add-a-code-snippet/

/**
 * Add quantity field on the shop page.
 */
function ace_shop_page_add_quantity_field() {

    /** @var WC_Product $product */
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

    if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() && 'variable' != $product->get_type() && $product->is_purchasable() ) {
        woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'min_value' => 1, 'max_value' => $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity() ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'ace_shop_page_add_quantity_field', 8 );

/**
 * Add required JavaScript.
 */
function ace_shop_page_quantity_add_to_cart_handler() {

    wc_enqueue_js( '
        $(".woocommerce .products").on("click", ".quantity input", function() {
            return false;
        });
        $(".woocommerce .products").on("change input", ".quantity .qty", function() {
            var add_to_cart_button = $(this).parents( ".product" ).find(".add_to_cart_button");

            // For AJAX add-to-cart actions
            add_to_cart_button.data("quantity", $(this).val());

            // For non-AJAX add-to-cart actions
            add_to_cart_button.attr("href", "?add-to-cart=" + add_to_cart_button.attr("data-product_id") + "&quantity=" + $(this).val());
        });

        // Trigger on Enter press
        $(".woocommerce .products").on("keypress", ".quantity .qty", function(e) {
            if ((e.which||e.keyCode) === 13) {
                $( this ).parents(".product").find(".add_to_cart_button").trigger("click");
            }
        });
    ' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'ace_shop_page_quantity_add_to_cart_handler' );
```

i Also have this code that changes the min value from 1 to 250 if the category is 250 and step value's 250 instead of 1.

```
// Funktion som kollar om produkterna har en aktiv kategori vid namn 250, om produkten/produkterna har det så sätt minsta order-antal till 250, varje steg (antal produkter du vill öka att lägga till) till 250. 

add_filter("woocommerce_quantity_input_args", function($args, $product){

    if(has_term("250", "product_cat", $product->get_id())) {
        $args['min_value'] = 250;
        $args['step'] = 250; 
    } 

    return $args;

}, 10, 2);
```

When i add more than one prodcut to the cart the value is correct  250x2 = 500
BUT when i add 250x1 to the cart the value goes back to 1 and not 250.

On the single page product page it works fine no matter if you add one or 1000..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some missing parts in your code, use the following instead:

```
// General quantity settings
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ){
    $terms      = array(250); // (can be terms Ids, slugs or names)
    $taxonomy   = 'product_cat'; // Product category taxonomy | For product tags use 'product_tag'
    $qty_value  = 250;
    
    if( has_term( $terms, $taxonomy, $product->get_id() ) {
        if( ! is_cart() ) {
            $args['input_value'] = $qty_value; // Starting value
        }
    
        $args['min_value'] = $qty_value; // Minimum value
        $args['step']      = $qty_value; // Step value
    } 
    return $args;
}

// For Ajax add to cart button (define the min and max value)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'custom_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg', 10, 2 );
function custom_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg( $args, $product ) {
    $terms      = array(250); // (can be terms Ids, slugs or names)
    $taxonomy   = 'product_cat'; // Product category taxonomy | For product tags use 'product_tag'
    $qty_value  = 250;
    
    if( has_term( $terms, $taxonomy, $product->get_id() ) {
        $args['quantity'] = $qty_value; // Min value
    }
    return $args;
}

// For product variations (define the min value)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_available_variation_min_qty', 10, 3);
function custom_available_variation_min_qty( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $terms      = array(250); // (can be terms Ids, slugs or names)
    $taxonomy   = 'product_cat'; // Product category taxonomy | For product tags use 'product_tag'
    $qty_value  = 250;
    
    if( has_term( $terms, $taxonomy, $product->get_id() ) {
        $data['min_qty'] = $qty_value; // Min value
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Or this can be done also centralizing settings in a function this way (does the same):

```
// Custom general settings to be loaded
function get_my_taxonomy_terms_qty_settings(){
    return array(
        'terms'        => array(250), // (can be terms Ids, slugs or names)
        'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat', // Product category taxonomy | For product tags use 'product_tag'
        'input_value'  => 250, // Default 1
        'min_value'    => 250, // Default 0
        'max_value'    => -1, // Deafult '-1'
        'step'         => 250, // Default 1
    );
}


// General quantity settings
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ){
    extract( get_my_taxonomy_terms_qty_settings() );
    
    if( has_term( $terms, $taxonomy, $product->get_id() ) {
        if( ! is_cart() ) {
            $args['input_value'] = $input_value; // Starting value
        }
    
        $args['min_value'] = $min_value; // Minimum value
        // $args['max_value'] = $max_value; // Maximum value
        $args['step']      = $step; // Step value
    }
    return $args;
}

// For Ajax add to cart button (define the min value)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'custom_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg', 10, 2 );
function custom_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg( $args, $product ) {
    extract( get_my_taxonomy_terms_qty_settings() );
    
    if( has_term( $terms, $taxonomy, $product->get_id() ) {
        $args['quantity'] = $min_value; // Min value
    }
    return $args;
}

// For product variations (define the min and max value)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_available_variation_min_qty', 10, 3);
function custom_available_variation_min_qty( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    extract( get_my_taxonomy_terms_qty_settings() );
    
    if( has_term( $terms, $taxonomy, $product->get_id() ) {
        $data['min_qty'] = $min_value; // Min value
        // $data['max_qty'] = $max_value; // Max value
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thank you, i have updated my code with the whole snippet for add quantity for shop page, i think that is causing some errors, bc your code doesnt seem to work

Comment: @emmbla My code works perfectly on normal WooCommerce site… See [those related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3730754%20woocommerce_quantity_input_args)… The problem come from your customizations on the archive (shop) page

Comment: Yes, thats true thank you. I just changed from number to string in the array and the code worked! Thank you so much.